# Double Value MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have a double value error. Upon checking online they indicated if checking between varchar and int might be the cause. However, both columns are varchar and when running a simple query, it runs perfectly.

This is the first statement with no error

```
SELECT storey_range, resale_price
FROM resale.flat_prices
WHERE storey_range > 10;
```

| storey_range | resale_price |
| --- | --- |
| 10 TO 12 | 3456 |
| 14 TO 16 | 12223 |

However when I run the following statement:

```
ALTER TABLE resale.flat_prices ADD storey VARCHAR(12);
UPDATE resale.flat_prices 
SET storey =
  case
    when storey_range < 9 then 'low_storey'
    when storey_range > 10 AND storey_range < 18 then 'mid_storey'
    when storey_range > 19 AND storey_range < 27 then 'high_storey'
    when storey_range is null then 'NULL'
    else 'Error'
  end
```

It throws this response Error Code: 1292. Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '10 TO 12'. I tried removing AND and put a comma still got an error. Tried Cast seems to not work. The data provided this range and I was trying to categorize it based on range.

On a side note, would overlapping storey in between, cause an error? like if the storey_range = 17 to 20.

Comment: You `storey_range` value is string, how you would expect to compare it to a number?

Comment: However you can convert `storey_range` to integer and then compare like: `CASE storey_range + 0 = 10 THEN...`

Comment: When I use the following:

`ALTER TABLE
MODIFY COLUMN storey_range INT`
It throws an Error Code: 1265. Data truncated for column 'storey_range' at row 1

Comment: It is because you already have some string data in your table. Either you need to delete (truncate) your table and then ALTER it, or update the values in storey_range column to integers and then ALTER.

Comment: I am curious on how to do this. Should I split them into two columns so I can remove the TO and still be able to find the range within by using two seperate columns? Like column a = 10, column 2 = 14. `SELECT * FROM X WHERE case
    when column 2 < 9 then 'low_storey'` Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Although I do get the answer by doing this, but I do wonder if there is a different solution:

```
ALTER TABLE resale.flat_prices ADD storey VARCHAR(12);
UPDATE resale.flat_prices 
SET storey =  RIGHT(storey_range,2);

ALTER TABLE resale.flat_prices
MODIFY COLUMN storey INT;

SELECT * ,case
    when storey <= 9 then 'low_storey'
    when storey >= 10 AND storey <= 18 then 'mid_storey'
    when storey >= 19 AND storey <= 27 then 'high_storey'
    when storey is null then 'NULL'
    else 'Error'
  end as storey
  FROM resale.flat_prices;
```